# Connecting to Denodo from AWS Glue Job

Tags: python, aws-glue, denodo

I am trying to add a new Glue Job that will connect to Denodo and pull data from there. I followed the [guide](https://community.denodo.com/kb/en/view/document/How%20to%20connect%20to%20Denodo%20from%20AWS%20Glue?category=Consumers)  from Denodo but I am still getting below error

> 2023-03-30 07:09:49,542 INFO [Thread-9] glue.AnalyzerLogHelper$ (Logging.scala:logInfo(24)): 2023-03-30 07:09:49,538 ERROR [pool-2-thread-1] utils.FileUtils (FileUtils.java:readCsvFile(29)) - Error getting file with getResourceAsStream

Here is how I'm doing the connection:

> db_username = "uname"
> db_password =  "pword"
> db_url = "jdbc:vdb://dvprod.company.net:9999/company_global_data"
> table_name = "tablename"
> jdbc_driver_name = "com.denodo.vdp.jdbc.Driver"
> s3_output = "s3://cp-aws-ss-prod-data/extracts/"
>
> Connecting to the source
>
> df = glueContext.read.format("jdbc")
> .option("driver", jdbc_driver_name)
> .option("url", db_url)
> .option("dbtable", table_name)
> .option("user", db_username)
> .option("password", db_password)
> .load()
> df.printSchema()
> print df.count()

I am getting the error in the connecting to the source part. The Denodo driver is uploaded in the correct folder in S3 and is declared in Dependent JARs path property of the job. Am I missing something?